# Access a table of a separate database using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC website with its own database and everything is working fine. Now I want to access a table of a database from a different MVC site. I added the connection string in the Web.config and named it `OldMvcDB`. Then I added a class to access this table:

```
public class OldSiteDB : DbContext
{
    public OldSiteDB() : base("name=OldMvcDB") { }

    public DbSet<OldTable> OldTables { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to access this table, I get the error:
`The model backing the 'OldSiteDB' context has changed since the database was created.`

This is because the old database has a lot of other tables so the context doesn't match.

**How can I access this one table without having to duplicate all the items in my new site?**

Comment: I think you must disable code-first as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663178/1942895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following to your class constructor:

```
Database.SetInitializer<OldSiteDB>(null);
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143116/122195) SO answer.